# Setting up to call a number of a label in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the variable that is a phone number `agency.phone` and i have a label that the number goes to on the view `agencyPhone`

I want to be able to click the label to call the number, I have found this code but not sure how to implement it in my situation:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:mymobileNO.titleLabel.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

Thanks for helping out a noobie!

Comment: replace your UILabel to UITextView

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create lable in IB and than add this code in your .m file

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        UITapGestureRecognizer* phone1LblGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(phone1LblTapped)];
        // if labelView is not set userInteractionEnabled, you must do so
        [agencyPhone setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [agencyPhone addGestureRecognizer:phone1LblGesture];
    }

    - (void)phone1LblTapped
    {
        UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
        if ([[device model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] ) {
            NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:agencyPhone.text];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
        } else {
            UIAlertView *Notpermitted=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Your device doesn't support this feature." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [Notpermitted show];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes I have done this and I think this is what I want. Although when I click the label it says device not supported, I believe that is because im using the simulator, correct?

Comment: yes, you cant dial number from simulator but if you use divice than this code will do the trick. and also if this answer help you then accept it.

Answer (score 4):

You should switch the label to a button and add the code you pasted to be executed when the button is pressed.

For example:

```
- (void)callPhoneNumber:(id)sender {
  NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:mymobileNoButton.titleLabel.text];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
}
```

Comment: He want to add it in label

Comment: It shouldn't be a label if he really wants button functionality

Comment: @radesix how do i label my button to my phone number variable (for the label I did self.agencyPhone.text = [agency phone]

Comment: UIButton has a titleLabel property

Comment: wow... look at the haters down voting a perfectly valid solution

Comment: its good solution but not perfect solution.he can use label in that code.better than button.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` for making `UILabel` clickable

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourClickMethod:)];
[titleLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[titleLabel addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

-(voidyourClickMethod{
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:mymobileNO.titleLabel.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
}
```

Make sure you set the property `userInteractionEnabled = YES` of `UILabel`

Answer (score 1):

you could handle click on the UILabel using `touchesBegan`

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGRect labelRect = yourLabel.frame;
    if( CGRectContainsPoint (labelRect, point))
    {
       //label was clicked
       //Add phone number handling code here
    }  

}
```